# Add condition to doctrine associations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Here is the case:
We have a `User` who can be in multiple `Groups`. A `Group` can be active or in active. If the `Group` is inactive i do not want them in the collection of `Groups` in the `User` object.

So if `$user->getGroups()` should only get the active groups.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [criteria filtering](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).